# How can I make my application install scripts to bypass User Account Control in Server 2008?

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2008

I've written a bunch of VBScripts to install software (like SQL Server Express, WSUS etc.) on my Server 2003 boxes which has all been fine.  I'm now adapting them to new Server 2008 boxes and they now won't run without bringing up the UAC prompt.

I know this is normal behavior, but is there any way I can disable UAC, run my install string and then enable UAC again?

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

[Technet on UAC in Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772207.aspx), in short use secpol.msc or gpedit.msc; you probably want to silently elevate ("No Prompt" is the actual value, the setting name itself varies depending on whether you're running as an administrator or a standard user) rather than disable UAC altogether.  Disabling UAC turns off a number of other features, most notably some virtualization, which could break some of the programs you install down the line.